# How to prove that $a_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{a_n}{a_n +1}$ is monotone increasing with $a_1=1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, golden-ratio, monotone-functions

This question has been driving me crazy, and I can't find the answer anywhere.

I tried proving it using induction.

As for the base case:

$a_1=1<1.5=a_2$

Next, suppose $a_k \leq a_{k+1}$

Then,

$$a_k \leq a_{k+1}$$
$$a_k +1 \leq a_{k+1}+1$$
$$ \frac{1}{a_k+1}\geq \frac{1}{ a_{k+1}+1} $$
$$ \frac{a_k}{a_k+1}\geq \frac{a_k}{ a_{k+1}+1} $$
$$ \frac{a_k}{a_k+1} +1\geq \frac{a_k}{ a_{k+1}+1}+1 $$

My goal was to get 
$$ \frac{a_k}{a_k+1} +1\leq \frac{a_{k+1}}{ a_{k+1}+1}+1 $$
$$a_{k+1} \leq a_{k+2}$$

But obviously, I was not able to find a way.

I also tried a different inductive approach where I noted 
$$a_{k+2}=\frac{5 a_n +3}{3 a_n +2}$$
You can check that this is true by seeing you get the correct $a_3=1.6$ using the given $a_1=1$.

Assuming $a_k \leq a_{k+1}$ I had that

$$ a_k \leq 1 + \frac{a_n}{a_n +1}$$
$$ \frac{a_n}{a_n +1} +1 \leq \frac{{a_n}^2 + 4a_n +2}{{a_n}^2+2a_n+1}$$

From the assumption $a_k \leq 1 + \frac{a_n}{a_n +1}$, we have that ${a_n}^2 \leq a_n +1$, so 
$$ \frac{a_n}{a_n +1} +1 \leq \frac{{a_n}^2 + 4a_n +2}{{a_n}^2+2a_n+1} \leq \frac{(a_n+1) +4a_n +2}{{a_n}^2+2a_n+1} =\frac{5a_n+3}{{a_n}^2+2a_n+1}$$

If only I could change the denominator the same way while keeping the direction of the inequality, I could substitute $a_n+1$ for ${a_n}^2$ and I would get the desired $\frac{5 a_n +3}{3 a_n +2}$, proving that $$a_{k+1} \leq a_{k+2}$$ since $$a_{k+2}=\frac{5 a_n +3}{3 a_n +2}$$.

How do I prove the sequence is monotonic increasing? Both of these routes did not get me to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  $\,a_{n+1} = 2 - \cfrac{1}{a_n +1}\,$, so $\,a_{n+1}-a_n=\cfrac{1}{a_{n-1} +1}-\cfrac{1}{a_n +1}=\cfrac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{(a_n +1)(a_{n-1} +1)}\,$.

Comment: By the inductive assumption, I have that the numerator is >=0. By showing that 0 is a lower bound, I have that each of the factors  in the bottom is >0, so their product is >0. So, I have the whole fraction is >0, which implies that a_n+1 >= a_n ?? Is that correct?? 

Thank you very much for the hint!

Comment: but would you be to able to explain how you get a_{n+1}=2 - 1/(a_n +1) algebraically??

Comment: @ddd $$a_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{a_n + 1 - 1}{a_n + 1} = 1 + \frac{a_n + 1}{a_n + 1} - \frac{1}{a_{n}+1} = 2 - \cdots $$

Comment: @ddd Right, the idea is to show by induction (or telescoping, which is itself a disguised induction) that the difference between consecutive terms keeps the same sign, so in the end the monotonicity is decided by $a_2-a_1 \gt 0\,$. As to how the fraction was simplified, thanks Zain Patel for explaining that in the previous comment. I'll just add that writing it that way just makes the calculations easier, but you can get the same result directly from the original form: $\require{cancel}a_{n+1}-a_n=\cancel{1}+\frac{a_n}{a_n+1}-\cancel{1}+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-1}+1}=\cdots\,$.

Comment: @dxiv sir can we say $f(x) = 1+(x/(x+1)), f'(x)= 1/(x+1)^2 >0 \implies$ a_n is increasing sequence. Can i prove like this? pls reply. I am a beginner in real analysis

Comment: @Magneto That only proves that $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ is a monotonic sequence, you still need to determine whether increasing or decreasing. Consider for example $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $a_1 = 1/2$ vs. $a_1 = 2$.

Comment: But sir we have $f'(x)>0 \implies f(x)$ is increasing function. So $a_{n}$ is increasing? Plscorrect me if i am wrng

Comment: @Magneto No, what we have is that $a_{n+1}-a_n=f(a_n)-f(a_{n-1})$, so $a_{n+1}-a_n$ and $a_n-a_{n-1}$ have the same sign. Whether that sign is positive or negative depends in the end on the sign of $a_2-a_1$. Again, try $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $a_1=2$, then $a_2=\sqrt{2} \lt a_1$, so the sequence is definitely not increasing.

Comment: @dxiv Oh okkk... by induction it will become monotonically increasing (a2>a1as 1.xx>1). I am talking about another method. As $a_{n+1} = 1+\frac{a_n}{1+a_n}$, i can express this as $f(x+1) =1+ \frac{x}{1+x}$. If f'(x+1)>0, then f(x+1) and so f(x) is increasing function. So, a_n is increasing. can you pls tell me is this way fine?

Comment: @Magneto `If f'(x)>0, then f(x) is increasing function`. That's correct. `i can express this as` No, that's not what the recursion is. What you have is $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ where $f(x) = 1 + x/(1+x)$. `So, a_n is increasing` No, that does not follow. Please read my previous comments again.

Comment: @dxiv Ok got it...$f(a_n)$ turned out to be monotonic. But why is this happening in this way sir? i just thought f(a_n) is increasing and so $a_{n+1}$ to be increasing... but when i subsitute, x=1/2 and x=2. It is different... Any clue sir?

Comment: @Magneto `i just thought f(a_n) is increasing` No, that would be increasing only if $a_n$ itself were increasing, but then you go into a circular argument. All you can say is that $a_n$ is monotonic, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201967/how-to-prove-that-a-n1-1-fraca-na-n-1-is-monotone-increasing-with/2201969?noredirect=1#comment5942448_2201969).

Answer (score 1):

You could also show that $1 + \frac{a_i}{a_i+1} > a_i$, by rearranging the inequality to get $2a_i+1>a_i^2+1$ then $2>a_i$. By showing $a_{n+1} = 2 - \frac{1}{1+a_n}$ (as in earlier answer) and that $a_i>0$, you show that $2>a_i$.